# SQL server Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is most likely a very simple query. I just cannot remember how to do this correctly.

I have a table that contains leads, state, and county.

I want to have it count the amount of leads for each county in certain states.

Comment: Please provide more detail regarding your table schema and example data.  In the rush to answer and comment on initial answers, it quickly became clear that it is critical to know whether "leads" means counts of leads that need to be summed, lead IDs or strings that need to be counted etcetera.

Comment: @J0e3gan Apparently it was a `COUNT`

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: Yes, apparently! Accepting the answer that guessed correctly is one way to respond to the comment. "You have chosen...wisely." :) LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what your table schema is like (columns, table name etc.) so I'm going to make a guess and here is the 'generic' answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(leads), COUNTY, STATE
FROM table
WHERE STATE = 'Texas'
GROUP BY COUNTY, STATE
```

Comment: `SUM(leads)` is likely a better fit than `COUNT(leads)`.

Comment: @J0e3gan English is not my mother tongue so I don't know what a `lead` is in this context.

Comment: @J0e3gan from where do you know that lead is even a numeric column?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: I don't come to think of it.  I assumed as much, and really it warrants clarifying with the OP, as does the assumption that it is non-numeric.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: No worries.  It occurs to me that natively speaking English or not, there really is not a way to know as the question stands whether "leads" means numeric or non-numeric values, whether to aggregate them with `SUM` or `COUNT` even if they are numeric (e.g. "leads" meaning sales reps' leads counts that need to be summed vs. FK lead IDs that need to be counted).

Comment: "You have chosen... wisely." :) LOL  Per my comment on @SoulTrain's answer, though, consider a subtly important extra grouping on `STATE` since many states have same-named counties - even if the OP didn't consider this subtlety.

Comment: @J0e3gan Yes, that would be an improvement if he would run the query for multiple states. I still don't know how he's going to use the query .. so from now on these are just speculations.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS...

```
SELECT 
COUNTY
, SUM(LEAD)
, STATE
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COUNTY, STATE
```

Comment: why use a `SUM`? When OP clearly states he wants a `COUNT`?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: "count" in the OP's question is informal I think - not an indication of the best aggregation to use.  By my read of the question, `SUM` is likely a better fit than `COUNT`.

Comment: @J0e3gan My assumption is that we shouldn't make assumptions.

Comment: @@J0e3gan  My thoughts exactly.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: Sure.  It a fair point.  Either way is an assumption, though - best addressed in a comment asking for clarification whether "leads" means lead counts to sum or individual leads to count.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, @DrCopyPaste: OP wants a **Count of the amount of Leads** which suggests a `SUM` instead of `COUNT`, to me atleast

Comment: @SoulTrain Either way this is a poorly written question. No sample data, no expected output, no table schema. We should just stop debating who's right until the OP gives more details.

Comment: @SoulTrain to me it is not that clear I must say, I see that `a table that contains leads` can be understood in different ways ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Agreed, the question is open ended

Comment: The extra grouping on `STATE` is subtly important.  Many states have same-named counties.

Comment: sum actually didnt work correctly i was getting an overload

Comment: @coreytoolis: "overload"?  We are not talking about C# methods, rather a T-SQL query: what do you mean by "overload"?